# When is it safe to use 'unsafe string modifications' in C#?

Tags: c#, string, pointers, unsafe

```cs
private const int RESULT_LENGTH = 10;

public static unsafe string Encode1(byte[] data)
{
    var result = new string('0', RESULT_LENGTH); // memory allocation

    fixed (char* c = result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RESULT_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            c[i] = DetermineChar(data, i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}


public static string Encode2(byte[] data)
{
    var chars = new char[RESULT_LENGTH]; // memory allocation

    for (int i = 0; i < RESULT_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = DetermineChar(data, i);
    }

    return new string(chars); // again a memory allocation
}

private static char DetermineChar(byte[] data, int index)
{
    // dummy algorithm.
    return 'a';
}
```

Both methods encode a byte array according some specific algorithm to a string. The first creates a string and writes to the single chars using pointers.
The second creates an array of chars and eventually uses that array to instantiate a string.

I know strings are immutable and that multiple string declarations can point to the same allocated memory. Also, according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents#unsafe-modifications-to-string), you should not use unsafe string modifications unless it is absolutely necessary.

My question:
    **When is it safe to use 'unsafe string modifications' as used in the Encode1 sample code?**

PS. I'm aware of newer concepts as [Span and Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx), and the [string.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netcore-2.1) method. I'm just curious about this specific case.

**Edit**

Thank you for all your responses.
Maybe the word 'safe' in my question was more confusing than it did any good. I didn't meant it as an opposite of the `unsafe` keyword but in a vernacular sense.

Comment: I think you're conflating the meaning of `unsafe` here.  There's no such thing as "safe" `unsafe` code.  The `unsafe` keyword is there to remind you that the usual safety mechanisms (such as buffer overrun protection) do not apply.

Comment: Its safe to use unsafe when the unsafe is safe - i.e. when you are certain you have not introduced any issues that would otherwise be dealt with by the CLR.

Comment: It is very naughty.  But you'll get away with it, this is not an interned string.  StringBuilder is the safe alternative.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by **safe**. There are any number of issues that you could introduce with `unsafe`. They could be serious or benign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the only time this is "safe" (in the vernacular sense, not in the `unsafe` sense) is when you own the string and it has not yet been exposed to any external code who may expect it to be immutable. The only time it is *common* to see this scenario is when you're constructing a new `string` and you *can't* just use the `GetString` methods on an `Encoding` - for example, because the source data is discontiguous and may span multiple `Encoder` steps.

So basically, the scenario shown in `Encode1` where it allocates a new `string` with a known length, then immediately overwrites the character data is the only reasonable usage. Once the string is in the wild: leave it immutable.

However, if you *even remotely* can avoid it: I would. It definitely makes sense in the context of `Encode1`, but...

One scenario to be especially cautious off: interned strings (constants, literals, etc); you *don't own these*.

Comment: IMHO, .NET would benefit from a `String` constructor or static factory function that could build a string given an array of `{Object, Start, Length}` structures, where each Object could either be a `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Char[]`, or a special flag object indicating that it should generate `Length` copies of `(Char)Start`.  Such a feature would eliminate much of the need to build strings in more complicated fashion.  Java could also benefit from such a feature, though for efficiency such a function may need to receive separate arrays for the objects and parameters.

Comment: @supercat : If I understand you correctly you mean something like the `string.Create(....)` method (.net core 2.1) 
Search for 'string.Create' in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) post written by Stephen Toub.

Comment: @CoenvandenMunckhof: I've not been following .NET for quite awhile.  I've long thought it should support a `Span` concept, and I'm glad to see it's received one, though I would have favored a `ReadableSpan` base type with derived types `WritableSpan` and `ReadonlySpan`. The `String.Create` looks interesting though using arguments of type `ref TState` might have been nicer than `TState` in some cases.

Comment: @supercat in implementation: spans are structs (actually "ref structs"), so no "derived types" etc; instead, there are implicit conversion operators - so a `Span<T>` can be implicitly treated as a `ReadOnlySpan<T>`